# Using openzeppelin-test-environment to test upgradeable contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, contract-upgrading

**openzeppelin-test-environment** is quite a new package, it doesn't tell how to initialize the upgradeable contract in the information below:

> https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-environment

Just a basic example from the link above:

```sol
const { accounts, contract } = require('@openzeppelin/test-environment');
const [ owner ] = accounts;

const { expect } = require('chai');

const MyContract = contract.fromArtifact('MyContract'); // Loads a compiled contract

describe('MyContract', function () {
  it('deployer is owner', async function () {
    const myContract = await MyContract.new({ from: owner });
    expect(await myContract.owner()).to.equal(owner);
  });
});
```

> How to add an upgradeable contract which doesn't have constructor but `initialize` method?

Answer (score 0):

What about using [`deployProxy`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/truffle-upgrades#migrations-usage)?

```
// migrations/NN_deploy_upgradeable_box.js
const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');

const Box = artifacts.require('Box');

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  const instance = await deployProxy(Box, [42], { deployer });
  console.log('Deployed', instance.address);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize the contract you have to deploy it as stated in the [OpenZeppelin-upgrades official doc](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades).

### If you're using [hardhat](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades/blob/master/packages/plugin-hardhat/README.md#usage-in-tests) you should have :

```
const { accounts, contract } = require('@openzeppelin/test-environment');
const [ owner ] = accounts;
const { expect } = require('chai');

const { ethers, upgrades } = require("hardhat");

describe('MyContract', function () {
  it('deployer is owner', async function () {
    const myContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract');
    const mycontract = await upgrades.deployProxy(myContract, [{ from: owner}]);

    expect(await mycontract.owner()).to.equal(owner);
  });
});
```

### If you're using [Truffle](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-upgrades/blob/master/packages/plugin-truffle/README.md#usage-in-tests) you should have :

```
const { accounts, contract } = require('@openzeppelin/test-environment');
const [ owner ] = accounts;
const { expect } = require('chai');

const { deployProxy } = require('@openzeppelin/truffle-upgrades');

describe('MyContract', function () {
  it('deployer is owner', async function () {
    const myContract = artifacts.require('MyContract');
    const mycontract = await deployProxy(myContract, [{ from: owner}]);

    expect(await mycontract.owner()).to.equal(owner);
  });
});
```